# Single word embedded in whole logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

[image]

I want a single word embedded in whole logo. How do i do it in adobe illustrator?

I want to design a logo like this. Kindly help me

Comment: Hi Ossama! What have you tried so far and what was the issues when you tried  to create this effect?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I don't know how to apply this effect. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Have a look at how to use the pathfinder tool in Illustrator and do some tests. Maybe learning how to use this will help you get the effect you're looking for. If it doesn't work, then post your attempts here!

Comment: Sir I appreciate you advising me but I have tried using pathfinder tool and I don't know how to embed a impression of single word in whole logo.

Comment: With due respect I would really appreciate if you could tell me how to implement this effect.

Comment: Did it work for you in the end?

Comment: No it didn't. How am I supposed to upload a picture here so that I can tell where I am stuck.

Comment: I closed your question because you are asking for a tutorial and that is off-topic.  If you want further help please make an [edit] with effort.  If you can show what you've tried I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type "SODMG" in the font you want it.
2. With new word highlighted go to Object >> Pattern >> Make
3. adjust settings to desired effect.
4. name pattern & select "done"
5. re-type "SODMG" (this will be for the large one)
6. go to Type >> Create Outlines
7. in your Swatches pallet, choose the pattern you just made, by
   clicking it
8. go to Object >> Transform >> Rotate
9. type in 25°, and uncheck "transform objects". make sure "transform
   pattern" is checked
10. go to Object >> Transform >> Scale
11. again make sure only "transform pattern" is checked
12. scale using uniform scale, probably around 20%
13. done.

[image: Example using OP's name]

Comment: Mykol you are a genius thank you so much for your help. Really appreciated. Thank you for teaching me this. :)

Comment: @OssamaQazi If the answer of Mykol works for you, you should mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to this answer. This is a great way to say "thank you" here! ;)

Comment: His answer helped me a lot but unfortunately I couldn't get this to work. I am succeeding in making the effect but I don't know how to implement it on the text. :(

Comment: @Mykol I need your help again man. I would much appreciate it if you could respond again. Please

Comment: @OssamaQazi You can edit your question and post some samples of what you have tried, and show us where you're stuck! Maybe Mykol or someone else will be able to tell you how to fix this.

Comment: Sir i have followed the steps which mykol has told me, but i think i am mising sonething thats why it wont work.

Comment: Can you help me with this if i upload step by step images of what i am doing?

Comment: So you are able to get the pattern made, but not put it inside the word?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can figure out why it didn't work for you, in AI CS5 for example, you don't have the Step 2 in @Mykol's answer, you need to replace step 2 with :

**2. With new word highlighted go to Edit >> Define Pattern..**

The rest stays the same.

Comment: Sir I have the 2nd option. Problem originated from the third option. As the panel opens and I don't what settings to choose and above its written "adjust settings to desired effect".