# how to embed a single word through out a logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Please can anyone help me how to implement this effect in the text. Kindly help me with this. I have been trying but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi Ossama Qazi, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I havea already seen the exact same question with the same image somewhere today, and it had an answer...Update: You asked the same question here : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61610/single-word-embedded-in-whole-logo and you got an answer ! PS: You should try again, even if the first time it didn't work, you did something wrong. Those steps will work.

Comment: Yes I have posted this question again. :( I have been working on it for almost 3 hours.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I am new here I didn't know that user is restricted to post the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

1. type the word you want to use in a new layer
2. right click the layer, rasterize type
3. create a new layer type the word and repeat it as many times as needed to fill up the canvas, rasterize if necessary.
4. make sure the layer with the words pattern is nested above the layer with a single word layer
5. right click that layer and select: create clipping mask

P.S. this instruction is for Photoshop not Illustrator.